# Why is apache (httpd processes) using swap space?

Tags: apache-2.4, memory-usage

Here is the output from *top*. I don't understand why the httpd processes are using swap space.

```
top - 13:49:45 up 28 days,  2:11,  4 users,  load average: 1.31, 1.32, 1.20
Tasks: 262 total,   1 running, 260 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 17.4%us,  1.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 80.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.1%st
Mem:  15404040k total, 15071684k used,   332356k free,   711036k buffers
Swap:  8388604k total,     6264k used,  8382340k free,  5362172k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  SWAP COMMAND                                                                                                                                                   
 1674 root      20   0 11372 1708 1704 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.06  852 udevd                                                                                                                                                      
 5639 apache    20   0  443m  14m 4840 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00  848 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
22758 root      20   0  443m  25m  16m S  0.0  0.2  16:21.29  848 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5550 apache    20   0  551m  27m  11m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.07  736 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5552 apache    20   0  551m  27m  11m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.05  736 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5566 apache    20   0  552m  29m  12m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.24  736 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5575 apache    20   0  551m  28m  11m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.25  736 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5638 apache    20   0  552m  28m  11m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.28  736 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5645 apache    20   0  551m  28m  11m S  3.3  0.2   0:00.10  736 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5519 apache    20   0  552m  28m  11m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.14  732 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5521 apache    20   0  551m  27m  11m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.09  732 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5536 apache    20   0  552m  28m  11m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.15  732 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5548 apache    20   0  552m  28m  11m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.15  732 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5567 apache    20   0  552m  29m  11m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.21  732 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5568 apache    20   0  552m  29m  11m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.45  732 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5642 apache    20   0  551m  28m  11m S  4.0  0.2   0:00.12  732 httpd                                                                                                                                                      
 5430 apache    20   0  553m  30m  12m S  0.0  0.2   0:00.50  728 httpd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are long-lived processes, this is quite normal: by default, the linux kernels does not use swap only when RAM is totally filled; rather, it uses swap to store (or swap) long-lived, but rarely used (inactive) memory chunks.

This behavior can be controller via the [`vm.swappiness` parameter](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-memory-tunables.html).

Anyway, I suggest you to don't change the default behavior if not having a very good reason to do that.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense. We had previously set vm.swappiness = 10. But that still leaves the OS some discretion to use the swap space. Cheers